# Help with regex: Anything inside a tag

Tags: .net, regex

I need to find anything inside a tr...

```
<tr class="class1">
    more tags here,
    multiple lines...
</tr>
```

How can I get anything that's between `<tr class="class1">` and `</tr>`?

thanks!

Comment: Regular expressions are not suitable for parsing HTML as HTML is not a [regular language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language). Please look into DOM parsers instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What regex will match text excluding what lies within HTML tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179779/what-regex-will-match-text-excluding-what-lies-within-html-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You need to use a real HTML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), regex isn't sufficient to perform this task.

That said, you can use a poor expression like this: `/<tr.*?>(.*?)<\/tr>/` where group 1 will have what's (generally) between the `<tr>` tags, but no guarantees on correctness...things like nested tags will throw this off. **You need to use a real HTML parser**.

Comment: I just need to get what's between the trs... doesn't matter if it's well formed or not, and what it is inside

Comment: It does matter if it's well-formed or not, because if you were to create a regex, you'd have to take that into account. Also there could be infinite nesting of `<tr>`s, and regexes are not recursive. HTML parsers are the way to go.

Comment: thanks, but nothing is matched... I'm using .net, any special settings should be set?

Comment: @開発者: see the corrected expression the `/` in `</tr>` had to be escaped. as far as I know there are no special settings required. You may not need the preceding `/` or trailing `/`.

Comment: You do need to drop the `/` for a .NET regex (`@"<tr.*?>(.*?)</tr>"`) and to set `RegexOptions.Singleline` to allow the dot to match newlines. Other than that, what @Daniel Vandersluis said...

Answer (score 0):

2 possibilites:

Client side: Jquery - http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works

Server side: Linq To Xml - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx

Examples can be added if needed. I however think that the articles I posted will be quite useful in getting you started.